# function for word frequency + dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am trying to create a function to take in a string and return how many times a word in it has been used (with the word) as a dictionary. I also want it to look for a specific list of words to search up the string when provided and return the frequency of the words in the given list found in the string.

Example,

```
stringfunc = "I went to school today, to learn!"
print(wordfunc(stringfunc))
```

should return

{'i':1 , 'went':1, 'to':2, 'school':1, 'today':1, 'learn':1}

And,

```
stringfunc = "I went to school today, to learn!"
print(wordfunc(stringfunc,wordlist=["I", "feel", "Great"]))
```

should return

{'i':1, 'feel':0, 'great':0}

This is what I have so far

```
def wordfunc(stringfunc,wordlist=[]):
    count_dict = dict()
    stringfunc=stringfunc.lower()  # i want it to be case insensitive
    word = stringfunc.split()
    for i in range(len(word)):
        x =  ord(word[i][-1]) # in the next few lines I am trying to get rid of special characters
        if (not(x>=97 and x<=112) or (x>=65 and x<= 90)): 
            word[i]=word[i][:-1] # if a word ends with , or ! i want it to discount last character
    for i in wordlist:
        if (i not in word):
            count_dict[i]=0
        else:
            count_dict[i]=word.count(i)
    return count_dict
```

When I try

```
stringfunc = "I went to school today, to learn!"
print(wordfunc(stringfunc,wordlist=["I", "feel", "Great"]))
```

I get

{'I':1, 'feel':0, 'Great':0} # i can't get a lower case i don't know why

and when I try

```
stringfunc = "I went to school today, to learn!"
print(wordfunc(stringfunc))
```

I get an empty dictionary {}

Can you help me identify my error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You "can't get lower case" because you didn't program it.  If the input supplies `wordlist`, then you blithely accept whatever is there.  In the given case, you have two words capitalized, so that's what comes out.  Instead, you need to convert every element of `wordlist` to lower case, just as you did with the input string.

BTW, do not give misleading names to variables: `stringfunc` is not a function.

The main loop will be *much* easier to read if  you quit playing games with ASCII code values.  Instead, simply use `isletter`.  If this is new to you, then I strongly recommend that you repeat your tutorial on string processing; you missed some useful things that you will now recognize.

That said, also look up the `collections` package, notably the `Counter` type.  Once you've cleaned out all but letters and spaces in your input string, you can do the main processing with

```
count_dict = Counter(stringfunc.split())
```